# Adding property in the defined interface of the typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two `interface` define as below.

```
  interface TitleFont{
      fontFamily:string;
      fontStyle:string;
      size:string; \\ need only for the title property.
      opacity:number;
   }
  interface ChartFont{
      fontFamily:string;
      fontStyle:string;
      opacity:number;
   }
```

Two property in my class is of defined interface type:

```
 class Chart  {
     title: TitleFont;
     chartTitle: ChartFont;  
  }
```

Size is the extra property added in `TilteFont` when compared to `ChartFont`. Is there any  way to define one interface and make use of it for both the property?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Would not be a solution here to use *inheritance* and extend `TitleFont` from `ChartFont`

```
interface ChartFont{
    fontFamily:string;
    fontStyle:string;
    opacity:number;
}
interface TitleFont extends ChartFont {
    size:string; \\ need only for the tilte property.
}
```

We still have two interfaces, but in many cases we will be able to work with just a base one *(ChartFont)* like this

```
var fontSetting1 : ChartFont = Chart.title
var fontSetting2 : ChartFont = Chart.chartTitle
...
// follows common behaviour for ChartFont interface
...
```

And if later needed, we can up-cast:

```
var titleFontSetting : TitleFont = <TitleFont>fontSetting1;
```